# How to pass data in a button event handler on a Google script extending a spreadheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Extending a Google Spreadsheet, I run a script showing some data in a sidebar. At the bottom I want to add a button to mail the data.

However I can't figure out how the data can be passed from button to handler:

1. There's no possibility to pass data into the event call;
2. There's no way to get the button object from the event info, I can merely get the ID, which is useless if I can't get to the uiInstance (created outside of the handler function).

So what's the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a callback element (possibly a panel wrapping everything you need) to the server handler  before assigning it to the button. For example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setId('myPanel').add(
    app.createTextBox().setName('boxExample')).add(
    app.createListBox().setName('listExample').addItem('A').addItem('B'));
  //                                                       ↓↓ this is what you need ↓↓
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('callbackFunction').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var btn = app.createButton(btn, handler);

  app.add(panel.add(btn));
  //show app...
}

function callbackFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('myPanel').add(
    app.createLabel(e.parameter.boxExample)).add(
    app.createLabel(e.parameter['listExample']));
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using PropertiesService

I found (I don't know how) Google Script offers a data storage service called [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).

Assuming, as in this case, the data is for user only, I would need to first store the data as such:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
userProperties.setProperty("myKey", "myValue")
// Note myValue will be a string, so to store an array, 
// you'd need JSON.stringify(myArray)
```

Then as the button handler is called, the script can retrieve the data easily:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
var myValue = userProperties.getProperty("myKey")
```

### Using Hidden Widget

An alternative seems to be the use of a ["hidden" widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden).

```
 function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   // Note that the name "appState" for callbacks, and the id "hidden" for
   // getting a reference to the widget, are not required to be the same.
   var hidden = app.createHidden("appState", "0").setId("hidden");
   app.add(hidden);
   var handler = app.createServerHandler("click").addCallbackElement(hidden);
   app.add(app.createButton("click me!", handler));
   app.add(app.createLabel("clicked 0 times").setId("label"));
   return app;
 }

 function click(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   // We have the value of the hidden field because it was a callback element.
   var numClicks = Number(eventInfo.parameter.appState);
   numClicks++;
   // Just store the number as a string. We could actually store arbitrarily complex data
   // here using JSON.stringify() to turn a JavaScript object into a string to store, and
   // JSON.parse() to turn the string back into an object.
   app.getElementById("hidden").setValue(String(numClicks));
   app.getElementById("label").setText("clicked " + numClicks + " times");
   return app;
 }
```

(code from linked reference)